# End animation before toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want, when the space key is pressed that bb8 starts/stops jumping smoothly not so suddenly in the code pen. I was wondering how I can make the toggle smoother.

[This is the code pen](http://codepen.io/ShaheerSaif/pen/WwYpwV?editors=0110)

`$('body').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
      $(".bb8").toggleClass('bb8-2',  1000);
    }
  });`